# combine script with mediaquerie

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want this script
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_navbar_hide_scroll
working only for a defined screensize. I tried out to combine it with following screensize-condition

if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 600)

but i am still missing something to get it working.

```js
<script>
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 600) {var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-50px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}}
</script>
```

```css
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
      }

#navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display:block;
  }

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  }

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
</style>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<div id="navbar">
  </div>


<div>  
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and what about a second wrapper inside the navbar? Its causing the function not to work anymore...

```
`<div id="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <div id="second div-id"><a href="#home">Home</a>   </div>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need a window width without scrollbars

`if (window.innerWidth < 600) { // your code here }`

with scrollbars

`if (window.outerWidth < 600) { // your code here }`

Here’s the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/londongrammar/2t40nkt1/7/).

Please note: the navbar script only being executed when you load the page in browser window smaller than 600px.
If you want it to be triggered not only on page load but also when scaling browser window up and down - you should use a [resize event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize) on window object.

And if you’re testing in fiddle browser - javascript running in the fiddle calculates the fiddle browser width, not the actual native browser width.

Comment: thanks for the alternative conditions! Can you fiddle an example please? I still just don't get my example running..

Comment: here is the fiddle :)

Comment: wonderful! It works! But when I add 2nd container/wrapper inside the navbar-container, the function doesnt work anymore. How to solve that?

Comment: it still works the same way regardless of the wrappers inside navbar - see updated fiddle. If the ID of the menu is still navbar - the code runs.

Comment: ok thanks! But the problem is: I need another id, due to styling issues..

Comment: But this is not a javascript problem. Use another ID in the script, otherwise, how does the script know which menu to hide if it's looking for #navbar which no longer exist? 

Regarding style issues - you shouldn't use ID selectors in CSS unless you know why you're doing this. ID selectors have priority over other kinds of selectors, and if your page grows - it becomes harder to maintain https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

The solution was provided for the question about hiding the menu at 600px width, if this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: The reason why I use IDs is, I want to have one of the parts (font/link) inside the navbar moving and changing size when responsive 600 mode hits. I would wonder if questions about the content of the navbar shouldn't be right here, when the java-function is affected by that? I understand you saying, that using "navbar" as wrapper ID and have another ID  inside that wrapper to adress just one special part of the navbar is not a good way? What elso to do then? Should I use getElementByClassName ("navbar")? Or what do you mean? Sorry I am a little confused now, I am not a pro ;-)

Comment: I assumed that you removed the #navbar and expected the script to still work. Please fiddle your code, otherwise, I'm also getting confused what exactly you're changing and what you're trying to achieve and why it's not working. But to answer your question - you can use as many wrappers as you like, each with its own ID, also you can use getElementByClassName in JS instead of getElementById on the element - either way, it also works. If you send the fiddle, it'll be much clear what's happening there and how to solve it :)

Comment: ok, thanks, while building the fiddle for you it suddenly works :-) I got questions left about the resize event. For what reason can I use it? Is it e.g hiding the navbar when you zoom on a smartphone (to prevent the fixed element to grow half of screen)? Or do you mean that resize is handling a scroll the same as a resize and also the same as an onload? Or do I need to combine these events somehow?